# How to compile a less file on demand?

Tags: less

I have an admin panel in which user selects some colors, and based on his choices, a `colors.less` file would be created in a specific directory.

Another file called `styles.less` imports `colors.less`.

I want to listen to `colors.less` and compile the `styles.less` whenever it's changed.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to create a theming function here? Better to do it in custom properties/css vars rather than trying to update less files from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use GULP: https://gulpjs.com

This script watches the colors.less for changes and compiles the styles.less:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

var path_less = '/css/less/';
var path_css = '/css/';

gulp.task('less2css', function () {
    gulp.src(path_less + 'styles.less')
        .pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path_css))
});

gulp.task('watchless', function() {
    gulp.watch(path_less + 'colors.less', ['less2css']);  // Watch the colors.less file, then run the less2css task
});
```